# Microsoft Graph API Attachment Search using C#

Tags: c#, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to search any keyword in Outlook mailbox including body, subject, attachment, etc using Microsoft graph API with C#.
For subject and body I am able to apply filter but same way its not working with attachments.
See the code below:

```
graphClient.Me.MailFolders.Inbox.Messages.Request().Expand("attachments") .Filter($"contains(subject, '{subject}')").OrderBy("Subject").Top(30).GetAsync();
```

I know in the filter I am passing the subject but I am not sure how to search the content in attachment.

Please provide me some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested the scene you described. But if you want to search for information in any part of the message (the sender name, subject, message body, or any **attachments**), you could choose to [use the Microsoft Search API in Microsoft Graph to search messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-messages).

The HTTP example here:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/search/query
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "entityTypes": [
        "microsoft.graph.message"
      ],
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "contoso"
        }
      },
      "from": 0,
      "size": 25
    }
  ]
}
```

It queries messages in the signed-in user's mailbox that contain the string "contoso".

Comment: Thanks for answering it quickly. I have already seen the link you mentioned. I need this behavior to work in C# code which is not happening. Can you help me with that ?

Comment: I also tried below code:



`List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption>
                {
                    new QueryOption("$search", "Work")
                };
                var messages = await 
   graphClient.Me.Messages.Request(options).Expand("attachments").GetAsync();`

Comment: @VinayGupta I don't think you can use `graphClient.Me.MailFolders.Inbox.Messages.Request().Expand("attachments")` to get the attachment content. You need to use `graphServiceClient.Me.Messages["messageid"].Attachments["attachmentid"].Content.Request().GetAsync()` to get the content of the attachment. Then try to use `$search` on it.

Comment: I am not sure this will work. Because I want to search across all the mails where If the search text is matching with subject, body, and attachment it should return that mail in the result. The above code is not working as **.Content** is not accessible.

Comment: @VinayGupta If so, you should use `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/search/query`.

Comment: I need this same logic with C# code. If you see my above comment where I have created queryOption object to achieve it but It didn't worked.

Comment: @VinayGupta Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/search-query?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp#request.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out but it didn't work as I am using Microsoft graph API and this code is introduced in beta version of it.

Comment: [Entity Type Issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet/issues/43)

Please see this. EntityType conversion issue is open in beta release and that is show stopper as of now